# PHP header include file works in one file and doesnt in other

Tags: php, html, css

I'm only starting to use PHP and have a question thats killing me.

I have Includes folder where my `header.php` and `footer.php` is included. In my `header.php` I have my html header tag. Including part of the body tag as its the same throughout the website. The problem I'm having is that I can't get my css files to connect to other pages that are in different directories. See example below, my files structure.

**index.php**

-(css)  bootstrap.css,  styles.css

-(inc) header.php,  footer.php

-(rooms) toddlers.php, montessori.php

-(other)  otherFile.php, andAnother.php

So `header.php` has links to `bootstrap.css`, `styles.css` and all images.

If I include the `header.php` in `toddlers.php` everything works fine. Then i go and include it in lets say `index.php` and none of my css or images show. In `header.php` I have this link to `bootstrap.css`:

`<link href="../bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Same for `styles.css` which will work in `toddlers.php` but not `index.php`.

This is my `header.php` include code in `toddlers.php`

```
    define("APPLICATION_PATH", realpath('../Sites/'));
define("CURRENT_PATH", getcwd());

$paths = array(APPLICATION_PATH, CURRENT_PATH);
set_include_path(implode($paths, PATH_SEPARATOR));

include('../inc/header.php');
```

How can I include all my images and css in `header.php` which is then included in any other file?

Comment: It looks like you have wrong paths. When you change to a different directory you must have in mind that the paths change and that your include files could need to be updated.

Comment: I understand that but is there a way I could accomplish that? because my header.php is included in all pages. Which some of them are in different directories.

Comment: Or should I create header.php include file in all directories?

Comment: 'include <file>' does not change the current working directory. So if you use relative paths in nested include files, then the path is relative to the original working directory, not where the current 'include file' lives. It can get very confusing. ;-/ As did this comment.

Comment: @webAwwards Debug my code doesn't literally mean **MY** code, learn more http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216018/how-to-handle-debug-my-code-for-me-questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use absolute links instead of relative ones.
Indeed, the html is included verbatim, and the css sheets are linked after php execution. It means the CSS inclusion will work for every page in the same directory as toddlers.php but not in the others.

Comment: If I'm developing on my localhost. And then move my website to hosting would absolute paths need to be updated?

Comment: Not necessarily. If you name your paths relative to the root of your hosting, which is given by the variable $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] everything will adapt automatically when you migrate.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use absolute URLs instead of relative ones. Another way would be ho have specific headers with relative paths for every directory. This is more bothersome, and only bebeficial if you change hosting, since you would have no update to do. Another way would be to use a PHP variable that you use in the included file to change the path depending on the page itself. So for example, the pages in the root directory would use something like $path = '' while the pages in internal directories would use $path = '../' and so on... Just make sure that you update the $path variable before inserting the included code.